# how to download mysql reference documentation in E-pub format

Tags: php, mysql, epub

**mysql website** says that you can download **MYSQl reference** in **E-Pub format**. but i have not see any download link to download this in E_pub format. please suggest me the steps or give **download link**, i want to study, please help me, **thanks**.
below is link.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/manual-info.html

Comment: please tell me whether is it possible to download this reference in epub kindle format ?

Comment: You could take a look  at      https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ 
here there is the doc in several format  in fit not present for epub at least i available as pdf

Comment: Thank for reply sir,  I am searching the way to download this in epub because Pdf format is not fit for Kindle devices. The link u give also shows that epub format is available on MySQL website.

Comment: I convert the 8.0 docs from PDF myselfe. [Download it](https://lab.zeroplex.tw/download/MySQL-8.0-Reference-Manual-Including-MySQL-NDB-Cluster-8.0.epub) if you need.